# ElasticBeanstalk/NodeJS ruining my month; Need to force update or get hook working

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been trying for several weeks to create a workaround for some issue with a node module that is giving me some trouble I still don't understand. My simple workaround which has proven to work is literally renaming a file 'Match.js' to 'match.js'.

The problem is because this needs to happen BEFORE npm start, deployment fails and reverts to an older version. I either need to be able to force EB to take my new version despite the failed start sequence, OR create a hook that renames this file prior to npm start. However, I am having a hard time figuring out when that hook should fire:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/21matchhack.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      DIR_NAME="/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/react-router/lib"
      FILE_NAME="Match.js"
      FILE_RENAME="match.js"
      cd $DIR_NAME
      if [ -f $FILE_NAME ]; then mv $FILE_NAME $FILE_RENAME; fi
```

From my understanding, EB unzips my new application version to /tmp/deployment/application in /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/20unzip.sh

```
set -xe

EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config  container -k app_staging_dir)
EB_APP_SOURCE_BUNDLE=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config  container -k source_bundle)

/usr/bin/unzip -o -d $EB_APP_STAGING_DIR $EB_APP_SOURCE_BUNDLE
```

To make things more confusing and frustrating, the following sequence seems to delete the temporary folder in the next deployment step /30config_clean.sh

```
set -xe

EB_CONFIG_STAGING_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config  container -k config_staging_dir)

rm -rf $EB_CONFIG_STAGING_DIR
mkdir -p $EB_CONFIG_STAGING_DIR
```

Where does my new version go if this directory is deleted in the next step after being unzipped? I haven't been able to deploy to production in 3 weeks because of a simple uppercase filename.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `preinstall` hook of https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts.

Something like this in `package.json`

```
"scripts" : {
   ....
   "preinstall":"mv Match.js match.js"   
   ....

}
```

Comment: Hmmm that is a good idea... however, because it is a node module I need to fix, I'm thinking it should be postinstall instead: "postinstall": "mv ./node_modules/react-router/lib/Match.js ./node_modules/react-router/lib/match.js"

Comment: Well unfortunately seems like EB does not run postinstall, so I tried prestart instead, still no luck :/ thanks for your help, I'm going to keep at it